# Efficient scraping using page.evaluate function in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

It's my first post on here, so I hope I'm posting my questions in the correct fashion - thanks in advance for your patience!

I'm using Puppeteer to scrape image sources from the following website:

> https://www.palaceskateboards.com/range/summer-2020/

Using the page.evaluate() in Puppeteer I can properly scrape an image sources using the following code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

var imgQuery, imgQuerySource;

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load" });

    await page.goto("https://www.palaceskateboards.com/range/summer-2020/", { waitUntil: "load" });
    await navigationPromise;

    var imageSource = await page.evaluate(() => {
        imgQuery = document.querySelectorAll("img");
        imgQuerySource = imgQuery[0].getAttribute("src");
        return imgQuerySource;
    });
    console.log(imageSource)

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Which correctly returns the first image source in console:

```
https://images.palaceskateboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Palace-2020-spring-ark-air-grn-8675-300x210.jpg
```

Success! However I'm having difficulty placing scraping all links for the length of imageSource. I've tried every solution I could find, including introduction of a for loop with .push() and also using other methods like page.eval$() however I'm unable to get it to fruition. Is anyone able to push me in the right direction to efficiently scrape all 108 values and place them into an array? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, so I deconstructed it to an array so that `.map` is available. After that, I replace every element in the array with the new value of `.getAttribute("src")`.

```
var imageSource = await page.evaluate(() => {
    imgQuery = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    imgQuerySources = [...imgQuery].map((e) => e.getAttribute("src"));
    return imgQuerySources;
});
console.log(imageSource)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks so much for your help. 